# Issuer redeems fungible tokens held by a another party

Tags: kotlin, corda

I've been trying to implement some logic to redeem fungible tokens my scenario is as follows:

I have an issuer party A which issues fungible tokens, these will be held by party B. I need to implement a scenario where Party A will redeem the tokens held by party B.

My flow would be something like:

1. Party A -> Issues Tokens Held By -> Party B
2. Party A -> Needs to redeem tokens held by -> Party B
3. Party A -> Asks for all tokens of a typeX from -> Party B
4. Party A <- Receives the tokens of the typeX  from <- Party B
5. Party A - Redeems the tokens received from PartyB
6. Party A -> **Sends a new fungible token that represents the typeY to -> Party B

**The quantity of fungibles tokens of typeY should be the same as the quantity of the tokens redeemed of typeX.

I know that natural behavior would be to ask B to redeem its tokens but due to some business cases I need to do it on the issuer side (Party A)

I am trying to achieve this by initiating a transaction in party A (aka the issuer), there I am proposing the following:

```
addMoveFungibleTokens() //Move tokens own by Party B back to the issuer Party A
addFungibleTokensToRedeem() //Party A redeems the tokens that were received from the Party B
```

It seems that whenever I execute the

```
addMoveFungibleTokens(transactionBuilder, serviceHub, amountToRedeem, PartyB, PartyA)
```

I am getting the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Insufficient spendable states identified for 50 TokenPointer(class com.template.states.TypeX, e4842e04-5ff2-4eb8-936e-ea3fee82c2fd).
```

Does anyone have an idea on how to achieve the behavior I pretend?
I am sure that party B has 50 tokens this commands returns me the tokens:

```
run vaultQuery contractStateType: com.r3.corda.lib.tokens.contracts.states.FungibleToken
```

It seems that for some reason the addMoveFungibleTokens() is trying to move token from the Party A (issuer) to Party B

---

### ## UPDATE 1 - TRYING TO CLARIFY THE PROBLEM ##

Fake scenario:

> PartyA acts central bank and emits money for PartyB. PartyA and B
>   share a group of states which allows them to track how much money was
>   issued. 
>   Besides this, whenever new money is emited, PartA also issues a token
>   with the amount of money issued, this money is held by partyB (I am
>   representing money as a fungible token here).
>   For some reason CountryX where PartyA and B operate is changing currency, due > to this the transactions in the old currency need to be converted into a
>   newCurrency. 
>   Initially Party A has two currency types oldCurrency and
>   one newCurrency Since oldCurrency is disappearing all the previous
>   transaction have to be converted to new currency.

PartyA (Issuer):

```
@InitiatingFlow()
@StartableByRPC
class PartyAAskTokens(val oldCurrency: String, val newCurrency: String, val partyB: Party): FlowLogic<SignedTransaction>() {

    @Suspendable
    override fun call(): SignedTransaction {
        val counterPartySession = initiateFlow(partyB)

        // Get the type that represents old currency - This can be improved with QueryCriterias
        val oldCurrencyTypeStateRef = serviceHub.vaultService.queryBy<CurrencyType>().states.filter { stateAndRef -> stateAndRef.state.data.currency == oldCurrency  }.single()
        val oldCurrencyTypePointer = oldCurrencyTypeStateRef.state.data.toPointer<CurrencyType>()

        // Get the type that represents new currency - This can be improved with QueryCriterias
        val newCurrencyTypeStateRef = serviceHub.vaultService.queryBy<CurrencyType>().states.filter { stateAndRef -> stateAndRef.state.data.currency == newCurrency  }.single()
        val newCurrencyTypePointer = newCurrencyTypeStateRef.state.data.toPointer<CurrencyType>()

        // Get state of the user 
        // This state allows to keep track on the quantity of tokens issued at a given time
        // For each puchase I am creating a new state (e.g. Date of the operation matters for historical reasons)
        val userOperationState = serviceHub.vaultService.queryBy<UserOperationState>().states

        // Keys of each one of the participants in the transaction
        val ownSignerKey = ourIdentity.owningKey
        val otherPartyKey = partyB.owningKey

        // Propose a currency conversion transaction
        val transactionBuilder = TransactionBuilder(serviceHub.networkMapCache.notaryIdentities.first())

        // Command identifies that this transaction is an exchange of tokens from an old type into a new type.
        val exchangeOldCurrencyForNewCommand = Command(UserOperationContract.Commands.exchangeOldCurrencyForNew(), listOf(ownSignerKey, otherPartyKey))
        transactionBuilder.addCommand(exchangeOldCurrencyForNewCommand)

        // Hold the amount that needs to redeem from the old currency
        var amountToRedeemFromOldCurrencyType:Long = 0

    // Propose new states for the state current state
        userOperationState.forEach { userOperation ->
            run {
                transactionBuilder.addInputState(userOperation)
                transactionBuilder.addOutputState(userOperation.state.data.copy(currency = newCurrency))

                // Generate a new token with new currency, this should match the units of the new state
                val amountOfToken: Amount<TokenType> = userOperation.state.data.amountOfCurrency of newCurrencyTypePointer
                val issueToken: Amount<IssuedTokenType> = amountOfToken issuedBy ourIdentity
                val fungibleToken: FungibleToken = issueToken heldBy counterPartySession.counterparty
                addIssueTokens(transactionBuilder, listOf(fungibleToken))

                // Keep track of the untis that need to be deleted
                amountToRedeemFromOldCurrencyType += userOperation.state.data.amountOfCurrency
            }
        }

        // Generate the amount to redeem
        val redeemQuantity =  amountToRedeemFromOldCurrencyType of oldCurrencyTypePointer

        // Notify PartyB that you are requiring this amount of token 
        counterPartySession.send(AmountRedeemRequest(redeemQuantity))

        // Get the token from CounterParty (PartyB)
        val fungibleTokenToRedeemStateRef = subFlow(ReceiveStateAndRefFlow<FungibleToken>(counterPartySession))
        //val fungibleTokens = counterPartySession.receive<List<FungibleToken>>().unwrap { it }

        // TODO: How to improve this code if there is an exception here I will loose all my old tokens that need to be redeemed.
        // ############## EXCEPTION_HERE ############## 

        // Redeem the token in transaction
        addTokensToRedeem(transactionBuilder, fungibleTokenToRedeemStateRef)

        // Sign the transaction using the your own key
        val iSignedTransaction = serviceHub.signInitialTransaction(transactionBuilder)

        // Ask others participants to sign
        val signedTransaction = subFlow(CollectSignaturesFlow(iSignedTransaction, listOf(counterPartySession)))
        return subFlow(FinalityFlow(signedTransaction, listOf(counterPartySession)))
    }
}
```

Party B (Holder):

```
@InitiatedBy(PartyAAskTokens::class)
class PartyBGiveTokenBack(val counterPartySession: FlowSession): FlowLogic<SignedTransaction>() {
    @Suspendable
    override fun call(): SignedTransaction {

        val tokenAmountToRedeem = counterPartySession.receive<AmountRedeemRequest>().unwrap { it }
        val (inputs, outputs) = TokenSelection(serviceHub).generateMove(
                lockId = runId.uuid,
                partyAndAmounts = listOf(PartyAndAmount(counterPartySession.counterparty, tokenAmountToRedeem.amountOfTokenToSendBack)),
                changeHolder = ourIdentity
        )

    // Send the token states.
        subFlow(SendStateAndRefFlow(counterPartySession, inputs))

    // Send the tokens  
        // Not needed because through the state I can get to the data.
        //counterPartySession.send(outputs)

        // validate data
        val stx = subFlow(object: SignTransactionFlow(counterPartySession) {
            override fun checkTransaction(stx: SignedTransaction) {
            // TODO: Check quantity of tokens to be redeemed is the same as the tokens to be issued
            // TODO: Check if the states point to new token type.
            }
        })

        return subFlow(ReceiveFinalityFlow(counterPartySession, stx.id))
    }
}
```

Even knowing that in this scenario party B is the one holding the
tokens, in this case Party A needs to propose currency conversion from
one currency to another.  As a result of this proposal the states
"userOperationState" need to be converted into the newCurrency, also
new tokens of type newCurrency to replace the old ones of oldCurrency
need to be generated (see in code from PartyA).  And lastly the old
tokens owned by the PartyB need to redeemed by PartyA (Only PartyA can
do this related with business logic on the original problem): To
achieve this I am moving all tokens for oldCurrencyType that still
exist on PartyB (holder) to PartyA (issuer) and I am redeeming them.

I am using the SendStateAndRefFlow and ReceiveStateAndRefFlow and it seems to be working. If there is an exception after receiving the token StateRef from PartyB (Look for this on PartyA code ##############
EXCEPTION_HERE ##############), PartyB seems to be keeping the old tokens.

I was told in the Slack channel that flows are not atomic, transaction are atomic and that the execution of a subFlow() will create a new transaction.
Based on this, I was expecting that a subFlow() would make its changes and in case of an exception being throw after it, only its changes would be preserved, but this is not what its happening, it seems that the transaction executed on the subFlow() was also rolled back. Can someone clarify this, or point me to some good documentation about subFlows?

Regarding the first problem:
I was not able to use this function addFungibleTokensToRedeem() in my code without moving the tokens back. Reason for this is that PartyA is the issuer of the tokens. Since I am using fungible tokens, when they are issued they are already held by partyB, due to this,
my vault has no tokens. The method mentioned previously calls this line of code:

```
 val fungibleStates = tokenSelection.attemptSpend(amount, transactionBuilder.lockId, queryCriteria)
```

and it seems that under the hood this method is accessing to the PartyA vault which does not have tokens...

Comment: My hunch is that you will need two transactions to achieve your goal: one Move from B to A and the other Redeem by A. The reason you get the exception is that A does not the 50 tokens in its vault yet. The Move needs to happen first.

Answer (score 0):

seems to me that what you are describing is almost the same thing that currently exists in the token SDK. Instead of writing a completely new flow, why don't you wrap the existing redeem tokens flows with additional flows that start with the issuer specifying which tokens should be redeemed? You can probably do it with only a few lines of additional code, I reckon.

Regarding why you are getting an exception, I've no idea unless I see the code. I suggest you start again by wrapping `RedeemFungibleTokensFlow` and `RedeemTokensFlowHandler` with flows that handle the starting of the redemption process with the issuer as opposed to the redeeming party.